# Access forbidden in Magento

Tags: magento, xampp

Can you please help me,

i am trying to access the direct image file from the media/customer/ folder, but its saying something like

```
Access forbidden!
```

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

localhost
05/15/12 14:13:26
Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.1 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

Any help please !! I know, its not an error from xampp, its something from magento, please help me out

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I venture to doubt, that this message is produced by Magento.

It exactly looks like the default `xampp/apache/error/HTTP_FORBIDDEN.html.var` of XAMPP:

```
Content-language: en
Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Body:----------en--
<!--#set var="TITLE" value="Access forbidden!"
--><!--#include virtual="include/top.html" -->

  <!--#if expr="$REDIRECT_URL = /\/$/" -->

    You don't have permission to access the requested directory.
    There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

  <!--#else -->

   You don't have permission to access the requested object.
   It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

  <!--#endif -->

<!--#include virtual="include/bottom.html" -->
----------en--
```

Unfortunately you don't write anything about how your code tries to access the image.

Please post the relevant code parts.

And please find the proper 403 message in the Apache `error_log` and post it, too.

Answer (score 1):

You should check your permissions settings in the media folder.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the directory where Magento is installed does not have permissions to access the Magento directory. This is an Apache error, not a Magento one.